# Conversão de charset

Tags: mysql

Tenho um site para desenvolver para um cliente e o banco de dados MySQL dele está assim:

> Database Properties: Character set: latin1--cp1252 West European; Collation: latin1_general_ci
>
> Já as tabelas estão todas assim: Character set: utf8--UTF-8 Unicode; Collation: utf8_general_ci

O novo banco será:

> Database Properties: Character set: Character set: utf8--UTF-8 Unicode; Collation: utf8_general_ci
>
> Já as tabelas estão todas assim: Character set: utf8--UTF-8 Unicode; Collation: utf8_general_ci

Esta diferença entre as propriedades do banco me forçarão a fazer alguma conversão dos dados para não perder acentuação e caracteres especiais?

Comment: tem mais alguma dúvida? faça um comentário

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não terá problemas, o Database Properties define o "padrão" que será usado na "criação de tabela" quando esta não for setada um charset ele pega o default do Database.

Como você já tem as tabelas tudo em utf-8, e vai mandar para um Database onde tudo é utf-8 não precisa fazer nada além de um backup/restore normal.